# force cli query of salesforce object with more than 2000 records

Tags: r, salesforce, command-line-interface

I just discovered the force cli tool.  How do I query for more than 2000 records?

I have it working for queries but it only returns 2000 and I need to get them all.

```
force query select Id, Name from Custom_Object__c --format:csv > custom.csv
```

this file has about 10,000 records and I am only able to get the first 2000.  The documentation of the cli tool does not mention many details, however it is much faster than the tool I am using, which R using the RForcecom library

Comment: I see that I can use OFFSET numberOfRowsToSkip but I would not know how to build a script in BASH to automatically guess the total number of rows and the build a query guessing the total amount of queries to do

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is use the `bulkQuery` function in the package `RForcecom`. Example:

```
all_leads <- "SELECT Id FROM Lead WHERE CreatedDate < TODAY"

rforcecom.bulkQuery(rforce_session, all_leads,object="Lead") -> all_leads_df
```

Selects `Id` for everything in `Lead` prior to today. Takes about a minute for me to do ~700k rows.

Answer (score 0):

The [**salesforcer**](https://github.com/StevenMMortimer/salesforcer) package can query millions of records quickly via the Bulk 1.0 API. Below is an example which returns all records and fields on the Contact object:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(salesforcer)
sf_auth(username, password, security_token)

# get all the fields on the Contact object (remove compound fields which 
# are not queryable via the Bulk API.
# https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/compound_fields.htm
contact_fields <- sf_describe_object_fields('Contact') %>% 
  filter(type != 'address', !grepl('Latitude|Longitude', name))

# build the SOQL
all_soql <- sprintf("SELECT %s FROM Contact", 
                    paste(contact_fields$name, collapse=","))

# query the records and fields
all_records <- sf_query(all_soql, "Contact", api_type="Bulk 1.0")
all_records
#> # A tibble: 2,039,230 x 58
#>   Id                 IsDeleted MasterRecordId AccountId   ...
#>   <chr>              <lgl>     <lgl>          <lgl>    
#> 1 0033s00000wycyeAAA FALSE     NA             NA       
#> 2 0033s00000wycyjAAA FALSE     NA             NA       
#> 3 0033s00000wycyoAAA FALSE     NA             NA
#> # ...
```